# TLS comunnication with OpenSSL RSA certificates supported but ECC not

Tags: openssl, cryptography, certificate, rsa, tls1.3

Can someone help me ? I have simple program written in c using OpenSSL library, which implements network communication on the localhost[client-server communicatiom] with TLS method. When i use RSA certificates it works fine, but when i use ECC certificates i will get error:

**Client side:** 28310000:error:0A000086:SSL routines:tls_post_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed:ssl\statem\statem_clnt.c:1888:

**Server side:** 244D0000:error:0A000418:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert unknown ca:ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1584:SSL alert number 48

where could be the problem ? I use OpenSSL version 3.0.7

I tried enable algorithms using function **SSL_CTX_set1_groups_list()** but not works

Comment: It looks like you have forgotten to include the intermediate CA certificate in the certificate chain. This happens for instance if your PKCS#12 file contains only one certificate instead of the leaf certificate up to - but please not including - the root CA. As the client doesn't get the intermediate CA it cannot verify the entire trust path up to the root in the trust store. This has of course little to nothing to do with the algorithm, it's just a configuration difference.

Comment: Can you give me some solution ?

Comment: No because I don't know your server setup. Check the TLS connection and check the number of certificates. All certificates up to the trust anchor / root certificate need to be included in the handshake. As indicated, you must make sure that your private key is associated with a certificate chain, which is usually longer than just 1 certificate.